# Shorten Conditional Statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Fairly simple question, not sure what I'm missing here...
I have something like this:

```
if(this == 18 || this == 19 || this == 20 || this == 21) { 
    ...
}
```

How can I shorten it? I've tried `if(this == 18 || 19 || 20...)` but that didn't work. I have about 50 more of those values to go so it would be great if I could.

Thanls.

Comment: why not `if(this > 17 && this < 22)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming a suitable shim for older browsers:

```
if( [18,19,20,21].indexOf(this) > -1) {
```

Or, alternatively:

```
if( "|"+[18,19,20,21].join("|")+"|".indexOf("|"+this+"|") > -1) {
```

Comment: +1 for including an alternative for browsers that predate `indexOf` on arrays.

Comment: There is also the polyfill for browsers that don't support array indexOf: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: See answers which use indexOf - much cleaner IMO

Assuming the data isn't sequential numbers (if it is just use this > min && this < max)

You could put them all into an array, then do a foreach on the array.
Inside the loop, do a comparison, if it matches do your logic and then break.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an array

```
if ([18, 19, 20, 21].indexOf(this) >= 0) {
     // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are sequential, you can do:

```
if(this >= 18 && this <= 21){
  ...
}
```

If they are not sequential, you can use an array and `indexOf`

```
var values = [18,19,20,21];
if(values.indexOf(this) !== -1){
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about creating an array and using indexOf?

something like

```
testArray = [18,19,20,21];
if( testArray.indexOf(this) != -1){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery also has a similar function [inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)()

> if( jQuery.inArray( this, [18,19,20,21] ) > -1) { ... }